# Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture, but which one?

Tags: android, bitmap, out-of-memory

I'm getting the wellknown "Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture".

```
Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture (3069x4320, max=4096x4096)
```

While debugging I was commenting out parts, until I found everything relevant commented out. No images were used in the stripped-down code.

I still got the same error, so..
how can I know which bitmap the LogCat is talking about?
Is there some kind of library which can leave me clues?

Comment: first, try to post the out of memory... that'll be a good start. Second, read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve (if you don't). Third: this library may help you https://github.com/davemorrissey/subsampling-scale-image-view is for using large bitmaps

Comment: so your app has no own drawables in the res/drawable* folders that exceeds 4000*4000 pixels and the app has no access to the internet to load bitmaps from there and the error still happens?

Comment: I edited my answer.
Yes, I was actually just showing an empty layout in the end. No images were shown or loaded. I hoped there might be a way to find out which bitmap the debugger is talking about. But I guess there isn't, which makes my question to vague and broad. I'm working on it. :)

Comment: 4320 looks like 1080 * 4 (XXXHDPI). What type of background do your have ? Bitmap, Color, NinePath? In additional check background `android:tileMode`